# What should I do if I have a relevant answer to a protected question?

Tags: discussion

I understand why I cannot answer the question [What is behind the “Indian Undergrad Research Experience”-spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41687/what-is-behind-the-indian-undergrad-research-experience-spam); it is because I only have 1 reputation on this site and the question is protected.

However, I think I have a relevant and useful answer from the perspective of an Indian undergrad currently enrolled at one of the mentioned universities. What would be the best way to contribute? Should I just comment with tl;dr of my answer or should I send the answer to some moderator who can approve it of not being "low-quality/spam" and post it?

Comment: It looks like you have 101 rep on this site, no?  (AFAIK there is no difference between your bonus "+100" earned from being trusted on other SE sites and 100 earned on this sit.)

Comment: No the association bonus does not count. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765

Comment: Seems odd to me the association bonus does not count. Seems as if you've amassed enough points somewhere else to get it that you understand to not answer a question with "Thanks!" or "Me too!"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have an answer that raises points not already represented among the existing answers, you should earn 10 rep here so that you can post it.

You can earn 10 rep by any of the following:

- suggesting 5 edits that are approved
- posting 1 answer (to an unprotected question) that gets 1 upvote
- asking 1 question that gets 2 upvotes

Comment: (Note that "here" means on the main site, not *here* here, on meta.)

Comment: why don't we temporarily unprotect the question, let the OP answers it, then protect it again? It seems that the OP has abandoned their will to earn rep and answer it.

Comment: @Ooker - Questions get protected when they are attracting a lot of activity from newcomers who don't necessarily understand the culture of the Stack Exchange. The threshold is quite low – a mere 10 points – so I don't think there's any need to start temporarily unprotecting questions for people who don't want to earn the 10 points before answering.

Comment: @J.R. I don't think it's beneficial to *us* to prevent an answer from a person who spends the effort to post a quality meta question to show the will of posting a quality answer.

Comment: @Ooker, thanks for your concern. I have been trying to come up with a proper question for the past few days (that has not already been asked and answered!) and I have posted one now.

Comment: @Ooker I don't think the cost of a mod having to dedicate time and coordinate with the OP for a single answer is worth it, especially when the bar is already so low.

Comment: @RogerFan but it's quick and simple